# Shortcut API Android multiple applicationId

Tags: android

So currently I added shortcuts to my app but I have two different package name for two different versions of my app. Using ${applicationId} inside shortcuts.xml does not work nor does a string resource reference. How do I point my targetPackage to point to the different applicationId to my productFlavors in my app?

Comment: It is just workaround, but I developed a simple gradle plugin for this case.  It creates xml for each flavor with correct targetPackage. Maybe it will help https://github.com/Zellius/android-shortcut-gradle-plugin

Answer (score 6):

> How do I point my targetPackage to point to the different applicationId to my productFlavors in my app?

Have a different shortcut XML file in each of your product flavors' `flavorname/src/res/xml/` directories.

> Using ${applicationId} inside shortcuts.xml does not work

At present, that is only for the manifest.

> nor does a string resource reference

Ideally, this would work, but is not supported at the present time.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to use ${applicationId} inside your shortcuts.xml, you can add the following to your build.gradle:

```
android {
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.mergeResources.doLast {
            println "Updating shortcuts.xml"
            ant.replaceregexp(match: "\\\$\\{applicationId\\}", replace: defaultConfig.applicationId, flags: 'g', byline: true) {
                fileset(dir: "${buildDir}/intermediates/res/merged/${variant.dirName}/xml", includes: 'shortcuts.xml')
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Note: This is not working with the latest Gradle version where the files get flattened before running this command is executed.